# Remove quotation marks from msg.payload in NodeRed

Tags: javascript, json, node-red

When i receive the final message with msg.payload in node red i get "9f1c56018530012421409d9c10582007"

how can i filter out the quotations marks in a message? s transport.

Anybody have an idea here how to remove them from the actual payload?

Comment: Any string value in JS should be wrapped by quotes, otherwise you'll get the syntax error. But those quotes won't come if you display the value. Try running in console `alert("9f1c56018530012421409d9c10582007")` => and you won't see any quotes

Answer (score 1):

If you are viewing that in the Debug sidebar, the quotes are just there to indicate it is displaying a String type - they are not part of the actual data held in `msg.payload`.

For example, if you configure the Debug node to also log to the console, you'll see the message in the node-red log without the quotes.